# Download new files into PhpStorm project

Tags: phpstorm

I created a "project from existing files" via sftp, and excluded some logfiles from syncing. Now I uploaded some new folders to the server - how can I get PhpStorm to download and index them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `Remote Host` side panel.
2. If you do not have it -- use `Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host` to bring it up.
3. Browse your remote system using it and choose `Download from here` from context menu. If such action is not available then you have some misconfiguration -- e.g. that path is excluded from deployment or not mapped at all.
4. Alternatively you may use `Deployment | Sync with deployed...` -- it will check for differences between local and remote (may take time if connection is slow or you have lots of files).

Comment: There are issues still open for the slow remote deployment performance of PHPStorm, please vote on them: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1547 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3268 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5580